# PhoneGap Application's requirement for installing Plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins

Can somebody Please specify all the application's required for installing plugin in PhoneGap Android app. And Steps to installing

Answer (score 0):

You could find all the plugins [here](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) , each one with its documentations where explains how to use it and how to install it.

Using [Cordova CLI](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/latest/guide/cli/), you can add plugins from its repository, for example

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

also you can list all plugins you have using

```
 cordova plugin ls
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: can you please tell me full steps and where to place code of onesignal push notification service or If you have any another way to send push notification.

Comment: Hi @DivyanshPratapSinghSatyam you can use "phonegap-plugin-push" read the documentation here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push